# How to find queries that use a given index for mysql?

Tags: mysql, aurora

I am looking to change indices on my MySQL table. My hunch was that one of the indices, that I am looking to remove, shouldn't be used. But it is being used, based on `table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage` data.
I want to find queries that use this index so I can reason what would happen to such queries and if they will fallback to another existing index.

Is there a place where MySQL stores query plans? Or any other way of finding the queries that use a given index?

Comment: Where do those queries com from? Some application code?

Comment: Yes. Rails framework.

Comment: Try the [percona toolkits pt-index-usage](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-index-usage.html).

Comment: There is not 100% reliable way to discover whether an index can be dropped.

Comment: would there be a information_schema.index_statistics table in Aurora? does it have `rows_read`?